# Getting garbage data doing realloc using a structure

Tags: c, visual-studio

I'm trying to create a self-expanding array of a structure.  I have had pretty good luck using this technique using an array of strings, but using a structure doesn't work.   Below is the code:

```
//  SO1.h
//
#pragma once

typedef struct {
    int tag;
    int type;
}structure;

structure* addElement(structure* userArray, size_t* userArrayLength, size_t* userArrayAvailable, const int tag);

void listArray();
```

This is the C code:

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "malloc.h"
#include "SO1.h"

const int   ARRAY_INITIAL_SIZE = 2;
const int   ARRAY_ADDITIONAL_SIZE = ARRAY_INITIAL_SIZE / 2;
structure* userArray;
size_t userArrayLength = -1;
size_t userArrayAvailable = ARRAY_INITIAL_SIZE;

int main()
{
    userArray = (structure*)malloc(userArrayAvailable * sizeof(structure));
    if (userArray == NULL) {
        printf("could not allocate memory\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    userArray = addElement(userArray, &userArrayLength, &userArrayAvailable, 13);
    userArray = addElement(userArray, &userArrayLength, &userArrayAvailable, 14);
    userArray = addElement(userArray, &userArrayLength, &userArrayAvailable, 15);
    userArray = addElement(userArray, &userArrayLength, &userArrayAvailable, 16);
    userArray = addElement(userArray, &userArrayLength, &userArrayAvailable, 17);
    userArray = addElement(userArray, &userArrayLength, &userArrayAvailable, 18);
    userArray = addElement(userArray, &userArrayLength, &userArrayAvailable, 19);
    userArray = addElement(userArray, &userArrayLength, &userArrayAvailable, 20);
    userArray = addElement(userArray, &userArrayLength, &userArrayAvailable, 21);
    userArray = addElement(userArray, &userArrayLength, &userArrayAvailable, 22);
    userArray = addElement(userArray, &userArrayLength, &userArrayAvailable, 23);
    userArray = addElement(userArray, &userArrayLength, &userArrayAvailable, 24);
    userArray = addElement(userArray, &userArrayLength, &userArrayAvailable, 25);
}

structure* addElement(structure* userArray, size_t* userArrayLength, size_t* userArrayAvailable, const int tag)
{
    (*userArrayLength)++;
    if (*userArrayLength > *userArrayAvailable) {
        *userArrayAvailable += ARRAY_ADDITIONAL_SIZE;
        userArray = (structure*)realloc(userArray,  *userArrayAvailable * sizeof(structure));
    }
    if (userArray == NULL) {
        printf("could not reallocate memory\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    userArray[*userArrayLength].tag = tag;
    userArray[*userArrayLength].type = 1;

    listArray();

    return userArray;
}

void listArray()
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i <= userArrayLength; i++) {
        printf("%2d   %d\n", userArray[i].tag,
            userArray[i].type);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Once I do the `realloc` I start getting garbage data.  The first two, and the last entries are okay, but the ones in the middle get replaced by "-842150451   -842150451".  The is the output:

```
13   1

13   1
14   1

13   1
14   1
15   1

13   1
14   1
-842150451   -842150451
16   1

13   1
14   1
-842150451   -842150451
-842150451   -842150451
17   1

13   1
14   1
-842150451   -842150451
-842150451   -842150451
-842150451   -842150451
18   1
:
:
:
13   1
14   1
-842150451   -842150451
-842150451   -842150451
-842150451   -842150451
-842150451   -842150451
-842150451   -842150451
-842150451   -842150451
-842150451   -842150451
-842150451   -842150451
-842150451   -842150451
-842150451   -842150451
25   1
```

I don't think Visual Studio has anything to do with it, but I upgraded to VS Community Edition 2019 16.1.4 and I'm still getting the bad data.

I'm sure this is a beginner mistake, but I can't see it.  Does anyone know what could cause this data to become corrupted?

**Update:**  I'm not sure where the exact difference is, but I made the changes suggested by Steve Summit, user3121023 and John Bollinger.  It *almost* fixed the problem.  Everything works okay until I get to the last entry.  (I also changed the code to update the .type field with the userArrayLength value.)  The output is as follows:

```
:
:
:
13   0
14   1
15   2
16   3
17   4
18   5
19   6
20   7
21   8
22   9
23   10
24   11

13   0
14   1
15   2
16   3
17   4
18   5
19   6
20   7
21   8
22   9
23   10
24   11
-33686019   0
```

Can anyone suggest why on earth the last entry would appear like this?

Comment: Are you expecting the new memory `realloc` gives you to be all 0?  It's *not* guaranteed to be, but if you accidentally assume that it is (which is a very easy mistake to make), you typically get weird results like this.  (And the first few calls to `realloc` very often *do* give you zeroed memory, so it's easy to mistakenly assume that your program is working during its first few tests on small inputs, only to have it fail spectacularly on more realistic input.)

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Steve.  I tried initializing the .tag and .type right after the `realloc`, but still got the garbage.

Comment: I don't see your exact problem, but its probably related to your use of `userArrayLength`.  I strongly recommend initializing it to 0 (not -1), testing whether it's `>=` to `userArrayAvailable` before deciding whether to reallocate, and incrementing it *after* you store each new value.

Comment: Agreed: your usage of `userArrayLength` is at least confusing.  I haven't spotted a specific error with it, but in a general sense, its usage is inconsistent with its name, and that's fertile ground for bugs.

Comment: Thank you @user3121023 and John Bollinger for both your replies.

Comment: You also need to fix the printing code, its going from 0, up to the count, change <= to <

Comment: Thank you @BlueStrat.  I have made that change and it *almost* works correctly.  See below.

Comment: On `listArray()`, are you sure your new code reads `for (size_t i = 0; i < userArrayLength; i++) { ` ?

Comment: Thank you again.  Yes.  But I had UB as @JohnBollinger stated below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using a poor convention for managing your `userArrayLength` variable.

One of the things people often find annoying about C at first is its use of 0-based arrays, but the reason C *chose* 0-based arrays is that it makes possible a very straightforward, internally-consistent, error-avoiding set of idioms for managing dynamic arrays like yours.

The first question to ask is, if your `userArray` is initially empty (as of course it is), why are you initializing its size as `userArrayLength = -1`?  (And I know the answer, but as I'm about to show, rearranging other parts of the program just a little bit will allow us to remove this hack.)

Much better to initialize `userArrayLength = 0`, and to rearrange the program so that at all times, `userArrayLength` contains the number of elements in the array -- not one more than, or one less than, or anything confusing like that.

I recommend making these changes:

1. Initialize `userArrayLength = 0`.
2. When you decide whether you need to reallocate, change `>` to `>=`, that is, test whether `*userArrayLength >= *userArrayAvailable`.
3. When storing data into the array, move the increment step `(*userArrayLength)++` *after* you store the new element in the array.
4. In `listArray`, go from 0 up to one less than `userArrayLength`, by writing `for (size_t i = 0; i < userArrayLength; i++)`.

With those changes, your program works for me.

The whole point of this exercise is to arrange that *the definition and use of the `userArrayLength` variable makes sense*.  If it is supposed to contain the length of `userArray`, then have it *actually contain* the exact length of `userArray`, not to have to always remember that it's always one less, or something.  (The technical term for this is trying to maintain a good *[loop invariant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_invariant)*.)

If you're working with arrays in C -- *any* kind of arrays, statically or dynamically allocated -- here are some rules you should follow.  (I'm not sure these rules are written down anywhere, and some people would claim that they're merely "idioms" or "conventions", but every competent C programmer will agree that this is the way you should do it the vast majority of the time, unless you have some really good, exceptional reason for doing otherwise.  In other words, they might as well be rules.)

1. Always use 0-based arrays.
2. If you have a variable which tracks how much of an array is currently in use, and if the array is initially empty, always initialize the "count" variable to 0.
3. When you store a new element in an array, always increment the "count" variable *after* you store the new element.  And since you're using 0-based arrays, the right subscript to use for the element being stored is precisely your "count" variable (not 1 more or less or anything confusing like that).
4. If you're using a dynamically-allocated array, and you're testing whether you need to grow the array before storing a new element, (a) do make this test *before* you store the new element, and (b) use a `>=` test between your "count" variable, and the variable that tracks the currently-allocated size.  (And, of course, the variable that tracks the currently-allocated size should track the currently-allocated size, not one more or one less.)
5. When you iterate over an array, always use the idiomatic `for(i = 0; i < N; i++` loop.

And if it seems like I'm making too big a deal about these "rules", here's a true story.  I've been working on this answer for about 20 minutes now, and I still don't know what the actual bug in the original program was.  I'm simply too lazy to figure it out. I immediately noticed the nonstandard `userArrayLength` usage, and that made the program too hard for me to think about.  So I quickly changed the program to use the "proper" idioms, and sure enough, the problem went away.

So this shows the benefit of those "rules".  Yes, I agree, blindly following rules can be dangerous. Yes, I agree, it might be instructive to figure out exactly why the original program, with its nonstandard usage, had the problem it did.  But if I don't have time to do that, simply changing to the accepted idiom (which I *know*, from many years of experience with it, always works) magically makes the bug go away, and I can move on.

One more point.  My "rule 3" says "always increment the 'count' variable *after* you store the new element."  This means that you will often have an expression like

```
array[i++] = newelement;
```

The key thing to notice here is that the postfix form of `++` is exactly what you want, and that using the prefix form `array[++i]` would be very, very wrong.

(In your case, since you had an array of structures, with multiple members to assign, using `++` isn't as natural, unless you took care only to use it on the last of the several assignments.)

Finally, it's also instructive to work through what the rules would be *if* C's arrays were 1-based.  I'm not going to lengthen this too-long answer by listing them, but they're not actually too bad.  (In fact I might have exaggerated back at the beginning of this answer when I made a bald assertion about "the reason C chose 0-based arrays".)  But -- call me crazy, or a hopeless C nurd -- I find it fascinating that if you ever found yourself inserting into 1-based arrays, the *prefix* autoincrement form -- that is, `array[++i] = newelement` -- would end up being the right choice.

Comment: Thank you so much for your considerate reply.  I will mark this as the correct answer, although if you see the update to the question you will see I have one unusual piece of data.

Comment: Perhaps you would care to also address the fact that when `addElement()` calls `listArray()`, the latter's use of the global `userArray` pointer may produce UB? That happens when reallocation is not performed in-place, because the global pointer on which `listArray` relies is not updated until `addElement` returns.

Comment: Nice catch by Jonh Bollinger, perhaps in the very didactic spirit of your already good answer, you could expand it by wrapping the Dynamic array state into a struct of its own. This would both fix the undefined behavior spotted by John and allow more than one array instance to be used.

Comment: I had put the `listArray` inside the `addElement` so I could follow the progress of the creation of the entries.  But that must have caused UB.  When I moved it to be after all the `addElement`s, it produced the correct results.  Thank you again.

Comment: Thank you again, Steve, for your incredible answer.  I have learned a good lesson today from the result of all your hard work.